# Can't filter using checkboxes in angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, angular-pipe

I have a project that displays a list of participants. What I would like to do is filter them by providers using checkboxes in real-time.

The participants:

```
[
    { 'name': 'test1', 'provider' : {'name': 'provider1'}}
    { 'name': 'test2', 'provider' : {'name': 'provider2'}}
    { 'name': 'test3', 'provider' : {'name': 'provider3'}}
    { 'name': 'test4', 'provider' : {'name': 'provider1'}'}
 ..
]
```

My html template is:

Here is the list of checkboxes that displays providers. I use this to filter participants.

```
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let provider of providers">
    <input type="checkbox" name="providers" value="{{ provider.name }}" [(ngModel)]="provider.checked"
    (change)="displayParticipantsByProvider($event.target.value)">{{ provider.lastName }}
</div>
```

And here is how I display the participants:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let p of participants">{{ p.name }} - {{ p.provider.name }} </li>
</ul>
```

And my filter function in the component is:

```
displayParticipantsByProvider(filterVal: any) {
    if (filterVal === '0') {
      this.participants = this.cathechParticipants;
    } else {
      this.participants = this.participants.filter((item) => item.provider.includes(filterVal));
    }
}
```

This filter returns only whichever checked item is. For instance, if provider 1 is selected from the checkbox, it returns participants where I have provider1 in it. If I select provider2 from the checkbox, it returns only participants with the provider2 in it. My goal is to load both of them since they both are selected. So, how can I load participants using multiple checkboxes which allows me to filter?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I have edited the question a little bit. Perhaps it's clear this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of selected items and match it against providers list, and add it to the participants array.

The following example is done with Angular Material.

```
export class AppComponent {
  selectedProviders: any[];
  providers: any[];
  participants: any[];

  providerChange() {
    this.participants = [];
    for (const sp of this.selectedProviders) {
      for (const p of this.providers) {
        if (sp.provider.name === p.provider.name) {
          this.participants.push(p);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.providers = [
      { 'name': 'test1', 'provider': { 'name': 'provider1' } },
      { 'name': 'test2', 'provider': { 'name': 'provider2' } },
      { 'name': 'test3', 'provider': { 'name': 'provider3' } },
      { 'name': 'test4', 'provider': { 'name': 'provider1' } }
    ]
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<mat-list-item class="primary-imenu-item" role="listitem">
    <mat-form-field class="select-form">
        <mat-select 
        placeholder="Providers" 
        name="providers" 
        class="filter-select" 
        [(ngModel)]="selectedProviders"
        (change)="providerChange()"
        multiple>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let p of providers" [value]="p">
            {{p.provider.name}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </mat-list-item>

  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let p of participants">{{p.name}}</li>
  </ul>
```

[**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mn-angular-material-select-multi)

Answer (score 0):

you could check the list of providers and see which have the 'checked' property set on true (you will make use of the ngModel binding)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let provider of providers;let i = index">
  <input type="checkbox" name="providers" value="{{ provider.name }}" [(ngModel)]="provider.checked"
  (change)="displayParticipantsByProvider()"><span class="font-weight-bold">{{ provider.name }}</span>
</div>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let p of participants">{{ p.name }} - {{ p.provider.name }} </li>
</ul>
```

**TS CODE**

```
participants = [];
 providers =  [
    { 'name': 'test1', 'provider' : {'name': 'provider1'}, checked: false},
    { 'name': 'test2', 'provider' : {'name': 'provider2'}, checked: false},
    { 'name': 'test3', 'provider' : {'name': 'provider3'}, checked: false},
    { 'name': 'test4', 'provider' : {'name': 'provider1'}, checked: false}
 ];
displayParticipantsByProvider() {
    this.participants = this.providers.filter((item, idx) => {
      if (item.checked) {

        return item;
      }
    });

  }
```

Comment: Better to enter code using provided markup in the StackOverflow editor than adding as images as it makes it harder read.